# SVG path : Animation and Merging

Tags: svg

I have two questions about SVG path in the example below.

1. How can I animate the paths one after each other ?
2. Can I merge it into one path ?

Sample:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1"  baseProfile="full"> 
<path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
<path d="M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2">
<animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,100;100,100" begin="0s" dur="5s" /></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the begin attribute of an animtation to the ID of another animation element + .end to begin it when the other animation ends? e.g.

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1"  baseProfile="full"> 
<path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
<path d="M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2">
<animate id="one" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,100;100,100" begin="0s" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
<animate attributeName="stroke" values="red" begin="one.end" dur="2s" />
</path>
</svg>
```

Not sure what you mean with point 2. Perhaps you should ask another question and make it clearer what you mean by merge into one path?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two paths into one by concatenating the values of the `d` attributes:

```
<path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
```

Since it has two M elements, it will start your animation twice. If you want to merge into into a single continuous path, try:

```
<path d="M11.25 59.5C32.55 46.62 44.69 28.76 50.45 19.62C51.73 17.59 52.5 16.28 54.5 19.25
        C61.23 26.55 78.59 44.06 87.45 51.16C90.18 53.34 93.06 54.96 96.5 55.75" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2">
<animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,200;200,200" begin="0s" dur="5s" /></path>
```

EDIT:

OK I think I see what you want now. I don't think it will work using a single path with multiple M commands as they cause new dash-arrays to start and that will affect your animation. You could try using the single joined path and then drawing white boxes over the bits you don't want, but that's hardly ideal.

This sort of gets the effect I think you're after:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  baseProfile="full">

    <path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2">
    <animate id="animate1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0,60" to="60,60" begin="0s" dur="5s"/></path>

    <path d="M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;stroke-dasharray:0,80">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0,80" to="80,80" begin="animate1.end" dur="5s" fill="freeze"/></path>

</svg>
```

It's also not ideal as you will need to change the length of the dash array depending on the length of the line. I've reduced it to 60 otherwise there's a big pause between when one animation starts and the other finishes (or rather, there isn't, but it looks like there is because it's continuing to increase the length of the dashes even though the dash already fills the line).

Comment: The first path is almost what I was looking for, but how can I draw this two lines one after each other (without linking them)  ?

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to do what I think you want, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help !

This is actually the result I was looking for :

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1"  baseProfile="full"> 
<path d="M52.25,14c0.25,2.28-0.52,3.59-1.8,5.62c-5.76,9.14-17.9,27-39.2,39.88" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2" >
<animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,200;200,200" begin="0s" dur="3s" onend="document.querySelectorAll('path')[1].style.display='block'"/>
</path>
<path d="M54.5,19.25c6.73,7.3,24.09,24.81,32.95,31.91c2.73,2.18,5.61,3.8,9.05,4.59" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;display:none" >
<animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,200;200,200" begin="3s" dur="3s" />
</path>
</svg>
```